# Unable to find a specification for `JXHTTP (= 1.0.0) while installing pod file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5, tumblr, cocoapods

Hi I'm trying to install Pod files for TumbrSdk and when I give this command Install pod It is giving ***me Unable to find a specification for `JXHTTP (= 1.0.0)*** this error.

Steps I'm doing
After setup Pod
 - I change directory to where I want to add podfile
 - Then typed command vim Podfile
 - Then Insert
  platform :ios, '5.0'

pod 'TMTumblrSDK'
 - Followed by :wq command thus far all went well
 - When I fire this command pod install
It gave me the above error

Has any1 faced this issue?? Please help if you have the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should make sure the `JXHTTP` spec exists in `~/.cocoapods/repos/master/Specs/JXHTTP/1.0.0/JXHTTP.podspec.json`

Assuming it doesn't and this is the issue you can redownload the entire master specs repo with:

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods && pod setup
```

Comment: Hay man I tried your answer and must have to admit that I'm not very good at linux command so asking this silly question that do I need to copy paste the lines in order to redownload master specs repo?? Because When I did it it says No file or directory exist for the first line and for second line it says Directory not Empty.

Comment: The first half of the command, before the `&&` should remove where the specs repo is stored on your computer entirely wiping out what was previously downloaded. Then the second part should redownload it fully. In theory this would fix any conflicts that were causing it not to be updated. You could also try `pod repo update` if you want.

Comment: I have already tried pod repo update and it says nothing to update. and as I said I have tried both the commands you have mentioned but no luck. thanks once again for your effort.